# How to @Inject object from different project module included as jar

Tags: jakarta-ee, vaadin, cdi, vaadin7

I am  using Vaadin-CDI in multi-module maven project with one module desired for common classes such interfaces, abstract classes and others. My problem is, that I am not able to *@Inject* class anotated *@UIScoped* as usual, which is placed in **core** module into another. I am still getting *UnsatisfiedResolutionException*

```
SEVERE: CDI Beans module deployment failed
javax.enterprise.inject.UnsatisfiedResolutionException: Api type [com.web.core.TestClass] is not found with the qualifiers 
Qualifiers: [@javax.enterprise.inject.Default()]
for injection into Field Injection Point, field name :  cls, Bean Owner : [DispUI, Name:null, WebBeans Type:MANAGED, API
 Types:[com.vaadin.ui.AbstractComponent,java.util.EventListener,com.vaadin.event.MethodEventSource,com.vaadin.server.Abs
tractClientConnector,com.vaadin.server.VariableOwner,java.lang.Iterable,com.vaadin.ui.HasComponents$ComponentAttachDetac
hNotifier,java.lang.Object,java.io.Serializable,com.vaadin.ui.LegacyComponent,com.vaadin.event.ConnectorEventListener,co
m.vaadin.event.Action$Notifier,com.vaadin.ui.Component,com.vaadin.event.Action$Container,com.vaadin.ui.SingleComponentCo
ntainer,com.vaadin.ui.HasComponents,com.vaadin.server.Sizeable,com.vaadin.ui.Component$Focusable,com.vaadin.server.Clien
tConnector,com.vaadin.ui.AbstractSingleComponentContainer,com.vaadin.shared.Connector,com.web.disp.DispUI,com.vaa
din.ui.UI], Qualifiers:[javax.enterprise.inject.Any,javax.enterprise.inject.Default]]
```

I have found some advice in IBM WebSphere Info called **2. Resolve an unsatisfiable dependency.**  (can be found here http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v8r0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.websphere.nd.multiplatform.doc%2Finfo%2Fae%2Fae%2Ftweb_troubleshoot_cdi.html). According to this, I checked my project's *Deployment Assembly properties* and core.jar is added correctly.

What next should I check ? Many thanks for answers !

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Your commons jar needs a `META-INF/beans.xml`. Did you check that?

Comment: Hi Jan, thanks for an idea ! First of all, I've changed common jar project facet from UtilityModule to EJBModule. That change caused creation of META-INF folder, where I've put an empty beans.xml file. Now it is working !

Comment: Glad to hear, thanks for accepting. Good luck with your project.

Comment: I had it under WEB-INF and moved to META-INF and it worked. thanks!